# Android custom view just like recent applications view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to achieve below view something like as shown below.

This is default view.

[image]

When I clicked on Diagnose it will look like

[image]

In above image the three horizontal strips in bottom it is indicating there are other menu. When i slide the strips or click on them it will open menu same as first image.

Is there a way of achieving same effect using standard Android toolkit or do I need to build custom widget? If so - which one would you recommend extending if any?